# how to access DOM elements in angular 4 service?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, service

I am able to access DOM elements components like below

```
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var $: any;
//component stuff 
$('.my_class').innerHeight();
```

I am trying to implement the same inside the service class, but dom elements and template is not accessible in the service class.

p.s: this is not duplicate of how to access them in components.

Comment: no. not duplicate. read my question

Answer (score 7):

You can access DOM from an Angular service using the plain javascript document object, with some little additions to your service:

```
// We import not only "Injectable", but "Inject" too, from @angular/core
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
// We import DOCUMENT from @angular/common. Be careful, because the old import from '@angular/platform-browser' is deprecated.
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

// Our standard service class in the usual way
@Injectable()
export class LoadingSpinnerService {

  // In the constructor we inject a dependency to DOCUMENT, of type HTMLDocument
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument) {     
    // We create a new div in the DOM, child of the body tag, <div id="LoadingSpinner"></div>
    var NewDomElement = this.document.createElement("div");
    NewDomElement.setAttribute("id", "LoadingSpinner");
    document.body.appendChild(NewDomElement);
  }
    
}
```

As you will probably know, you crete the service from the command line with something like:

```
ng g s loading-spinner
```

Don't forget to edit the app.module.ts to add the "import" to the service, and the item to the "providers" array in its "@NgModule" decorator:

```
import { LoadingSpinnerService } from './WHATEVER-DIRECTORY-YOU-CREATE-THE-SERVICE/loading-spinner.service';
(...)
providers: [LoadingSpinnerService, 
(...)
```

About the topic of using angular services only for data, i don't agree. As you can read in the official architecture guide for services:

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

> Service is a broad category encompassing any value, function, or feature that an app needs.
>
> A component can delegate certain tasks to services, such as fetching data from the server, validating user input, or logging directly to the console.

The provided example just in this documentation is for a log data service.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't in services. You can do it javascript way like `document.getElementById`.

In components and directives You can use `ViewChild` from `@angular/core`

HTML:

```
<div class="my_class" #myElement></div>
```

TS:

```
    import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


    @ViewChild('myElement') myElement:ElementRef;
```

```
console.log(this.myElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight); // inside any function.
```

I guess you cannot directly access with CSS selectors by Angular way. Alternatively, you can just use plain old JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
```

**Note:** You can only do this in `components` and `directives` not inside `services`

**Why Services**

> Components shouldn't fetch or save data directly and they certainly shouldn't knowingly present fake data. They should focus on presenting data and delegate data access to a service.

Source: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

In Simpler terms:

- component, directive for presenting, manipulating and interacting with DOM
- services are for data handling between your component and backend

Comment: that's my question. how to access them in services.

Comment: You can't. Understand the difference between components and services. Updated My Answer check that